# Sharpssh directory listing

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

I'm writing an application that allows me to up- and download files from a remote server. I'm using sftp as my transfer protocol and i need to list all files and directory's into a listview. I'm using sharpssh for sftp. Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Thanks in forward,

Bas van Ooyen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Sftp sftp = new Sftp(serverUri.Host, userName, password);

sftp.Connect();

//the foldername cannot be empty, or the listing will not show
ArrayList res = sftp.GetFileList("/foldername");
foreach (var item in res)
{
    if (item.ToString() != "." && item.ToString() != "..")
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

sftp.Close();
```

Comment: I basically did the same thing... I'm working on updating some of the SharpSSH code that we use at https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh